# How to make a table scrollbar look the same in both windows and mac

Tags: qt, qml

`TableView` in QML is really wierd in my opinion at least on `QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

It's happening the following in windows:

[image]

on mac:

[image]

Why are they so different?? I don't understand. How can i make them the same.

As we can see on windows the scrollBar starts at the top of the table, but on mac it starts below the header.

Below i provide the code for the table:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 300
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }

    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        TableView{
            id:table
            anchors{
                //top:chooseColum.bottom
                topMargin:10
                left:parent.left
                right:parent.right
                bottom:parent.bottom
            }

            model: libraryModel

            headerDelegate: Rectangle{
                id:recHeader
                width:styleData.width+20
                height:30
                color:"blue"
                border.color: "black"
                border.width: 1
                Text {
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    //color:globals.text.textColor
                    text:styleData.value
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
            itemDelegate: Rectangle {
                border.color:"black"
                border.width: 1
                Text
                {
                  text: styleData.value
                  elide: Text.ElideRight
                }
            }


            TableViewColumn {
                id: col1
                role: "title"
                title: "Title"
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "author"
                title: "Authors of this tutorial"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for now it's not an option to update QT to 5.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Quick Controls 1.x are supposed to provide a native look and feel to your UI. I don't know how macOS displays scroll bars, but if it is different from Windows it will be the case for Qt Quick Controls 1.x.

You have got two solution for this :

1. Consider switching to Qt Quick Controls 2.x, but they do not handle native L&F.
2. Customize your scroll bars : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-styles-qmlmodule.html

Comment: thanks, i've already worked with ```TableViewStyle``` but in this case i'm not finding a way to make the vertical scrollbar go to top in both windows and mac.

Comment: Tbh i find the native L&F of TableViewStyle for macos really bad, so the future solution might pass as you say by implementing Qt Quick Controls 2.x.